# Le tutoiement de Dieu ?

Tags: vouvoiement, religion, tutoiement

J'ai récemment appris que, apparemment, le tutoiement est employé plutôt que le vouvoiement quand on parle avec/à Dieu. Ça m'étonne un peu, en tant qu'anglophone, et du coup je me suis demandé si c'est le cas depuis toujours, ou si ça remonte à un événement relativement récent.

Concrètement, peut-on retracer les origines de cette pratique, et en particulier, a-t-elle toujours été en vigueur ?

Comment: Je ne comprends pas pourquoi le tutoiement de Dieu étonne anglophone. Pour mémoire, *The Lord's Prayer*: "Our Father which art in heaven, Hallowed be thy name. Thy kingdom come, Thy will be done in earth, as it is in heaven.  Give us this day our daily bread...".  Cette remarque mise à part, la question est très vaste car de quel Dieu parle-t-on ? Quelle(s) religion(s)?

Comment: Pour s'en tenir aux prières en français, ne considérons donc que les religions chrétiennes. Dans le protestantisme on a toujours tutoyé Dieu (les raisons spirituelles influant le  linguistique, expliquer pourquoi n'est peut-être pas le lieu sur FL). Pour le catholicisme c'est depuis 1966, une conséquence de Vatican II et de l'abandon total de la messe en latin. Rentrer dans les arcanes de Vatican II ne me semble pas non plus approprié ici.

Comment: @None We learners are given a simplified set of rules. Use *vous* out of politeness or respect for authority, and *tu* informally with friends and family members. When in doubt, use *vous* to avoid offence. This leads us to the dilemma of which takes priority: familiarity with God or respect for his infinite authority? Seems safer to go with respectful than overly intimate. (There's a whole psychology of religion paper that could be written from that conclusion!) It takes a lot of deepening of our knowledge of French norms to realize the nuances to the terms "respect" and "familiarity".

Comment: As an Anglophone, it probably shouldn't surprise you: "Thy kingdom come,
thy will be done, on earth as it is in heaven."

Comment: @LukeSawczak Talking to God is a religious gesture that has nothing to do with everyday life or secular morality.  Talking God has to do with religion, which is a law in itself, it takes precedence on whatever local rules are. What I mean is that protestants will always use *tu/Du/thou/*... when the language has the means. When Catholic mass & prayers were in Latin then no choice to be made in the local language... and "the dilemma of which takes priority: familiarity with God or respect for his infinite authority?" is not on topic on FL.

Comment: @LukeSawczak I really the question has to do with general knowledge and religious education and not with one language in particular.

Comment: @None But the fact that it's a problem for Anglophones tells otherwise :) You have to realize that the *you/thou* analogy doesn't work for us, because that distinction has become pretty meaningless to us; it no longer has any concrete examples that feel intuitive that you can use to demonstrate the distinction. Only well-educated Anglophones will make much sense out of that. But it's fair to say that this is a question of tu/du/thou *languages* in general, not just French. (Except, of course, insofar as any of the languages that have a *tu/vous* distinction differ among themselves.)

Comment: Relegating it to the religious sphere means that one would resolve every *tu/vous* dilemma as a workplace question, an interpersonal skills question, a socioeconomic question, etc. Yes, it's the logic of those fields that influences *tu/vous* usage, but there are also generalizations; the field intersects with the internal logic of a *tu/vous* language. But I concede that there are cases where we defer to a field's logic and override the generalization. In which case, imo, it's a valid French question whether one follows the general *tu/vous* rules or has to consider the given field primarily.

Comment: I think it's an interesting question

Comment: @LukeSawczak The question is clearly not about the general use of *tu* & *vous* in French (and we have already plenty of those on FL) . The question shows OP already has a background on when to use *tu/vous* in secular situations, they think *vous* would be appropriate to talk to God tells they know *vous* shows respect,  and their question is solely about talking to God and religion. I answered in a comment with details that have nothing to do with French.

Comment: And this no more or less of a problem for anglophones than it can be for francophones or any -phones who do not know that Protestants have always used *tu/thou* to talk to God and Catholics changed after Vatican II. I'm sure lots of French people don't know this because it is a religious matter.

Comment: Je suis absolument convaincu que si un francophone se retrouvait subitement face à face avec Dieu, il le vouvoierait.

Comment: Les prières *Je **vous** salue Marie* mais *Notre père qui **es** aux cieux, que **ton** nom...* C'est ce qu'on dit pour ne vouvoyer que la sainte Marie dès les traductions de Vatican II.  Est-ce que tu as remarqué le tutoiement en anglais ?

Comment: @livresque j'ai personnellement toujours récité le Notre Père avec "vous"... Les quelques fois où j'ai entendu quelqu'un tutoyer Dieu, c'étaient des hommes ou femmes d'église, réels ou fictifs. Et à chaque fois ça m'amuse un peu...

Comment: Quand Jésus est doublé en français dans le [téléfilm](https://youtu.be/6RL8fnsZ9pM) de Zeffirelli, c'est l'impératif au singulier !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dieu étant écrit au singulier dans la question, on peut raisonnablement penser qu'elle fait référence au monothéisme.

Les textes sur lesquels s'appuient les trois grandes religions monothéistes sont tous écrits dans des langues (hébreu, araméen, grec, latin, arabe) qui ne connaissaient que le tutoiement.

Tant que les textes liturgiques sont lus dans ces langues, le problème du choix ne se pose pas, ce qui n'est plus le cas quand il s'agit de les traduire dans la langue vernaculaire.

Il semble que les traductions du Coran et de la Torah utilisent le tutoiement, mais je ne sais pas trop où chercher.

Pour ce qui est de la Bible, les plus anciennes traductions du *Pater Noster* en (ancien) français utilisent le tutoiement (Matthieu 6:9):

> *Li nostre Perre ki **ies** es ciels,
>
> seit seintefiez li **tuns** nuns.*
> *Psalterium Latino-Gallicum*, XII<sup>e</sup> siècle

> *Nostre Peres qui **es** el ciel,
>
> **ton** non soit saintefiés.*
> *Bible française du XIII<sup>e</sup> siècle*

> *Nostre Pere Qui **es** es cieulx
>
> **Ton** nom soit sainctifié*
> *Raoul de Presles, fin XIVe siècle*

> *Peres nostres qui **es** es chiuls,
>
> **tes** nons soit saintefiés.*
> Picard XV<sup>e</sup> siècle

Source: [Le « Notre Père » en ancien français du moyen-âge](https://jecherchedieu.ch/priere/notre-pere-priere/le-notre-pere-en-ancien-francais-du-moyen-age/)

En comparant vingt-sept traductions plus récentes disponibles [sur ce site](http://djep.hd.free.fr/LaReferenceBiblique/?Livre=40&Chap=6&Vers=9), on peut observer que le tutoiement prévaut largement, par exemple:

> *Nostre Pere qui **es** és cieux, **ton** Nom soit sanctifié.*,
> Pierre-Robert Olivetan (Calviniste), 1535

Seules les traductions de 1667 (Bible de Mons, Lemaistre de Sacy), 1895 (Abbé Fillion) et 1923 (Abbé Crampon) optent pour le vouvoiement:

> *Notre Père qui **êtes** aux/dans les cieux,
>
> que **votre** nom soit sanctifié*

On peut donc dire que le vouvoiement de Dieu est relativement tardif et qu'il était limité à l'Église catholique.

Voir par exemple l'ouvrage suivant qui traite ce sujet : *[Lettres sur la coutume moderne d'employer le Vous au lieu du Tu, et sur cette question : doit-on bannir le tuteyement de nos versions, particulierement de celles de la Bible ?](https://archive.org/details/lettressurlacou00verngoog/page/n2/mode/2up)*, Jacob Vernet, 1752.

Depuis Vatican II (1962), le tutoiement est officiellement rétabli dans la liturgie catholique.

Cela dit, il s'agit là de prières apprises et récitées, pas d'une conversation spontanée. Dans une certaine mesure, ce tutoiement est moins celui de la proximité/familiarité qu'un archaïsme, à l'image des *Thou/Thy/Thee* bibliques anglais. Je suis absolument convaincu que si un francophone se trouvait soudainement face à Dieu, il ne lui viendrait pas une seconde à l'esprit de Le tutoyer.

Answer (score 2):

Pour résumer les commentaires et mes maigres connaissances en la matière :

Les protestants ont, semble-t-il, toujours utilisé le tutoiement.

Les catholiques ont toujours utilisé le vouvoiement, jusqu'à Vatican II. Pour qui, comme moi, ne connaît les prières que par les livres, les personnages de romans vouvoyaient Dieu, et Prévert écrivait encore "Notre Père qui êtes aux cieux, restez-y..."
Je n'ai découvert qu'assez récemment que le texte du patenôtre avait été modernisé (tutoiement, "notre pain de ce jour" en place de "notre pain quotidien" et quelques autres) et à mon sens il n'y a pas gagné...

Je suppose que les cathos traditionalistes utilisent toujours le vouvoiement.

Comment: Le Notre Père n'est-il pas dit en latin chez les traditionalistes ? (*Pater noster, qui **es** in caelis, sanctificetur nomen **tuum** ; adveniat regnum **tuum** ; fiat voluntas **tua**...*)

Comment: Cette réponse est vraiment de parti pris car la question mentionne Dieu sans autre précisions et il me semble que Dieu est présent dans beaucoup d'autres religions que le protestantisme et le catholicisme. La question est mal posée et n'a rien à faire ici, je l'accorde à ta décharge,  car elle porte sur des pratiques religieuses non spécifiques à la langue française mais aux dogmes religieux.