# Majuscule à "Vous" pour s'adresser au pape ?

Tags: majuscules, vouvoiement

Je suis en train de traduire un document qui est adressé au pape par des catholiques. Je sais qu'il est d'usage chez les croyants de mettre des majuscules aux pronoms personnels qui se rapportent à Dieu, mais est-ce qu'ils mettraient aussi des majuscules à *Vous*, *Votre*, etc. en s'adressant au pape ?

La version originale le fait, mais c'est une langue dans laquelle il n'est pas rare de mettre des majuscules pour indiquer le vouvoiement, en tout cas dans les lettres. En français, j'hésite, je n'ai encore jamais eu à m'adresser à des personnages royaux (ou, comme ici, le pape).

L'expression « Votre Sainteté » a l'air de s'écrire le plus souvent avec une majuscule, mais je ne sais pas si les règles sont différentes parce que c'est un terme d'adresse.

Comment: L’usage est d’écrire au Pape à la troisième personne du singulier en employant le terme « Votre Sainteté » en lieu et place de « Vous ».   https://www.modele-lettre.com/lettre-2484/lettre-de-lettre-au-pape.  Mais Mattieu Ricard [lui écrit](https://www.matthieuricard.org/blog/posts/lettre-au-pape-francois)  avec vous et sans majuscule.  Mais tout le monde n'est pas Mattieu Ricard, tu  risques d'avoir des avis très divergents.

Comment: Même si on vouvoie le pape, on peut [tutoyer Dieu](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/47134/le-tutoiement-de-dieu) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Dans la section 101 du *Bon usage* 14ième édition,  au « 3° », on peut lire ceci.

> *Sa, son, votre,* etc. prennent la majuscule dans les titres *Sa Majesté, Votre Majesté, Son Excellence, Votre Éminence*, etc. :
> ♦ Quelles sont les intentions de VOTRE Honneur ? (VERNE, Enfants du capit.
> Grant, I, 2.)
> ♦ Ma présence auprès de Sa Grandeur (HUYSMANS, Cathédrale,
> p. 57).
>
> Écrivant aux personnes portant ces titres (plus rarement lorsqu'on
> ne s'adresse pas à elles), on met aussi la majuscule, spécialement dans les
> documents officiels, aux possessifs et aux pronoms personnels se rapportant aux dites personnes :
> ♦
> Je prie VOTRE Altesse Royale de me permettre de Lui écrire une fois encore.
> Si ELLE pense que j'ai déjà trop abusé de Sa bienveillance, ELLE n'aura qu'à laisser
> cette lettre sans réponse (BERNANOS, Corresp., juillet 1939, lettre à la comtesse
> de Paris).
> ♦ Il VOUS incombera, Sire, de désigner les premiers membres de la future Académie (j. DESTRÉE, rapport au roi, dans l'Annuaire de l'Acad. roy. de
> langue et de littér.fr. [de Belgique], 1991, p. 96).
> ♦ C'est dans cette conviction que Je  VOUS prie, cher et grand ami, de l'accueillir avec VOTRE bienveillance accoutumée (lettre de créance d'un ambassadeur donnée par le président de la République française, dans Reuter et Gros, /. c.).

Il semble que l'on doive inclure les dignitaires de l'église dans la liste (rois, ambassadeurs, gouverneurs, etc), puisque « éminence » est un titre honorifique des cardinaux ([réf.](https://eglise.catholique.fr/glossaire/eminence/)).

Comment: Merci ! Je vais mettre une majuscule, alors.